# How to use Regular Expression in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, regex, web-crawler, stringtokenizer

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(remaining, "\t\n\r\"'>#");

String strLink = st.nextToken();
```

The input to string *remaining* can be one of the following :

1. `"http://somegreatsite.com">Link Name</a>is a link to another nifty site<H1>This is a Header</H1><H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>Send me mail at <a href="mailto:support@yourcompany.com">support@yourcompany.com</a>.<P> This is a new paragraph!<P> <B>This is a new paragraph!</B><BR> <B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.</I></B><HR></BODY></HTML>`
2. `"mailto:support@yourcompany.com">support@yourcompany.com</a>.<P> This is a new paragraph!<P> <B>This is a new paragraph!</B><BR> <B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.</I></B><HR></BODY></HTML>`

I know that the `StringTokenizer` constructor will split the string `*remaining*` into tokens using the regular expression.
But I unable to understand the regular expression used here.

The `strLink` will have the following value based upon the value in the string `*remaining*`:

1.`http://somegreatsite.com`
2.`mailto:support@yourcompany.com`

Please help me in understanding the regular expression used in the code above.

Comment: each of the characters passed in following `remaining` will be treated as delimiters and every time one of those delimiters is encountered the input string will be split into a token.

Comment: `"\t\n\r\"'>#"` is not a regular expression. It's just a simple list of chars.

Comment: Reading the javadoc really helps when you're a Java developer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Obligatory link: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

These characters `\t\n\r\"'>#` are not regular expression, but delimiters. You can see meaning of special characters in [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, for example.

```
\t - The tab character
\n - The newline (line feed) character
\r - The carriage-return character
\" - this is just a double quote
', >, # - other symbols
```